# Java setting data to JTable from database error

Tags: java, database, swing, jtable

when i try to show data from my database in table this way:

```
    void AddOrderToTable(JTable projectTable) throws SQLException
{
    zadanie=connect.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
    sql="SELECT * FROM Orders ;";
    dane=zadanie.executeQuery(sql);
    int n=0;
    while (dane.next())
    {
    uzsakNr=dane.getString("Uzsakymo_nr");
    if (uzsakNr != null) {uzsakNr = uzsakNr.trim();}
    priemDat=dane.getString("Priemimo_data");
    if (priemDat != null) {priemDat = priemDat.trim();}
    irengPav=dane.getString("Irenginio_pavadinimas");
    if (irengPav != null) {irengPav = irengPav.trim();}
    model=dane.getString("Modelis");
    if (model != null) {model = model.trim();}
    tip=dane.getString("Tipas");
    if (tip != null) {tip = tip.trim();}
    serial=dane.getString("Serijinis_nr");
    if (serial != null) {serial = serial.trim();}
    priedai=dane.getString("Priedai");
    if (priedai != null) {priedai = priedai.trim();}
    giedAprasy=dane.getString("Gedimo_aprasymas");
    if (giedAprasy != null) {giedAprasy = giedAprasy.trim();}
    status=dane.getString("Statusas");
    if (status != null) {status = status.trim();}
    grazDat=dane.getString("Grazinimo_data");
    if (grazDat != null) {grazDat = grazDat.trim();}
    pastabos=dane.getString("Pastabos");
    if (pastabos != null) {pastabos = pastabos.trim();}
    prieme=dane.getString("Prieme");
    if (prieme != null) {prieme = prieme.trim();}
    clientId=dane.getString("ClientId");
    if (clientId != null) { clientId =  clientId.trim();}


    projectTable.setValueAt(uzsakNr, n, 0);
    projectTable.setValueAt(priemDat, n, 1);
    projectTable.setValueAt(irengPav, n, 2);
    projectTable.setValueAt(model, n, 3);
    projectTable.setValueAt(status, n, 4);
    projectTable.setValueAt(clientId, n, 5);
    n++;
    }
    zadanie.close();
}
```

i get error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:432)
at javax.swing.table.DefaultTableColumnModel.getColumn(DefaultTableColumnModel.java:276)
at javax.swing.JTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(JTable.java:1812)
at javax.swing.JTable.setValueAt(JTable.java:1926)
at GetFromDb.AddOrderToTable(GetFromDb.java:195)
at Remontas.newItemMenuItem_2_actionPerformed(Remontas.java:754)
at Remontas$NewItemMenuItem_2ActionListener.actionPerformed(Remontas.java:710)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1849)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2169)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:420)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:258)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:302)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1051)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:1092)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:5517)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3135)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:5282)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:1966)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:3984)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2024)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4212)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:3892)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:3822)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2010)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:1791)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:3819)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:463)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:157)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:149)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:110)
```

where is problem?

Comment: Hint #1: create some helper method that will handle _if not null then trim the value_ code - [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Hint #2: Stop using [Ponglish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponglish) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that the table model is trying to display before you've got any data.  If the source data isn't loaded yet, you need to handle that condition rather than attempting to access the objects that are still null.

Answer (score 1):

Note that [`ResultSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) columns are numbered from 1, while [`JTable`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html) columns are numbered from 0.

Comment: i know, but it has no sense i dont use ResultSet numbering onlynames of columns